# iCloud - Check the storage used by Notes?

Tags: icloud, notes.app

I recently created a note with some large photos (~100 MB in total) in Notes and the note is synced with iCloud.

I want to check the storage used by Notes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**iPhone:** Go to Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > Manage Storage
**Mac:** Go to System Preferences > Apple ID > iCloud > Manage...

You can see the storage used by Notes App in the list.